# Dll interop and memory management concerning arrays

Tags: c#, .net, interop, marshalling

My question is about memory usage when interoping dlls in .Net (I am using C#, but the answer should apply to other .Net languages).

Say I have a C function in a dll that takes an array:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) void Func(int * arr, int len);
```

I have a choice of two corresponding calls in C#:

```
[DllImport("Lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Func([In] IntPtr arr, [In] int len);
```

Or:

```
[DllImport("Lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Func([In] int[] arr, [In] int len);
```

If the C function does not deallocate the array, will the latter interop method cause a memory leak by assuming the C function will free the marshalled array or will the interop system know to free the marshalled array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no leak when you use the second option. The marshaler simply pins the array, and passed the address of the pinned object to the unmanaged function. When the unmanaged function returns the array is unpinned.

The pinning is an optimization for arrays of blittable types. Were you passing an array of non-blittable types then the marshaler would take care of all memory lifetime.